# Two wordpress servers setup with Nginx

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I am trying to set up **2 wordpress servers with Nginx**.

Both sites are up and running fine:

https://server.io/learn

https://server.io/event

However, I cannot access the page I created:

https://server.io/learn/2016/06/we-can-get-you-hired/

For /learn or /event, nginx can access the right content folder.

```
/srv/server.wordpress/event/index.php > GET /event/ HTTP/1.1
/srv/server.wordpress/learn/index.php > GET /learn/ HTTP/1.1
```

But for https://server.io/learn/2016/06/we-can-get-you-hired/, **it is wrong.**

```
/srv/server.wordpress/index.php > GET /learn/2016/06/we-can-get-you-hired/ HTTP/1.1
                    ^
                    It doesn't go to the subfolder /learn.
```

The error log:

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header 
from upstream,  request: "GET /learn/2016/06/we-can-get-you-hired/ HTTP/1.1", 
upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "server.io", referrer: 
"https://server.io/learn/"
```

---

Here are my configuration files:

File: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/server

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name server.io *.server.io;
    return 301 https://server.io$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    server_name server.io *.server.io;
    location /learn {
        root /srv/server.wordpress;
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location /event {
        root /srv/server.wordpress;
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        root /srv/server.wordpress;
        include fastcgi_shared.conf;
    }
}
```

File: /etc/nginx/fastcgi_shared.conf

```
fastcgi_cache  microcache;
fastcgi_cache_key $scheme$host$request_method$request_uri;
fastcgi_cache_valid 200 304 10m;
fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating;
fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 1M;
fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
fastcgi_index  index.php;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include        fastcgi_params;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nginx serving content from the wrong "virtual host" while accessing with https](http://serverfault.com/questions/382606/nginx-serving-content-from-the-wrong-virtual-host-while-accessing-with-https)

Comment: Please show update with the configuration that shows what ports nginx is listening on.

Comment: @user5870571 I updated the configurations.

Answer (score 0):

You want to enable WordPress multisite and put this in your ngix configuration

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/wp-.*) /wp$1 last;
rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/.*\.php)$ /wp$1 last;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Now, all of them lost the subfolder. 

/srv/server.wordpress/index.php > GET /learn/ HTTP/1.1

/srv/server.wordpress/index.php > GET /event/ HTTP/1.1

/srv/server.wordpress/index.php > GET /learn/2016/06/we-can-get-you-hired/ HTTP/1.1

Comment: Do you mind if we move this to chat and then I will update the answer? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41881/two-wordpress-servers-setup-with-nginx

Comment: Yes, I have joined.

Comment: Can you join again and add me in the room? I can't type.

Comment: I tried multiple times and it won't add your username.